# Android Studio: my sms app is not one of the options for default SMS app

Tags: java, android, sms, manifest, default

I'm new to android app development so bear with me.

I've made a SMS app and are now trying to give the user the option to make the app the default SMS-app.
I've read that the app is supposed to be able to do everything the standard SMS app can before it can become the default SMS-app.
The functions the app can is: send SMS and receive and read incoming SMS.
I've also made the broadcastreceivers for receiving MMS and the service for quick response.
These do not do anything but is there so my phone thinks that the app is capable of everything an SMS app is supposed to do.

I've made it so when the user opens the app, the app checks if the app is the default SMS-app. If not, it will ask the user if the user wants the set the app as default. The problem is that my app isn't showing up as one of the options for default SMS apps.
I think it's because of the phone don't think the app is capable of everything an SMS app needs to do, and therefore isn't showing it as one of the options.

Heres my Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imessages">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".editNameAndPhoto_activity" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".MySMSReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".MyMMSReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android:permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".QuickResponseService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".Messages" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Again I'm new to this so i've included absolutely everything into the Manifest that will make my app look like it's a SMS app. There might be some stuff in there that shouldn't be there.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `.MySMSReceiver` intents filter from `SMS_RECEIVED` to `SMS_DELIVER`, everything else looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It didn't work though.

Comment: I know that they have changed a lot of security on the later versions of android. Does it change anything that this is being developed for android 9?

Comment: You have a typo in `"android:permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH"`. That colon should be a period, though that might just be here, as I would imagine that your IDE would complain about it. Also, in the `Messages` `<activity>` element, the `<action MAIN>` and `<category LAUNCHER>` need to be in their own separate `<intent-filter>`. That is, you'll end up with two `<intent-filter>`s for that `<activity>`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It didn't work. I've been "faking" the MMS and other needed services so I think I'll just finish the app and then see if I can make it the standard app then. 
Thank you though. Please feel free to comment again if you find the reason.

Comment: Yeah, you still needed to keep the change that Pawel suggested. I was pointing out further issues. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: It's my fault. I tried Pawel's suggestion but apparently it didn't work (must have done something wrong). Today I just tried it again and it worked. I'm sorry it's my fault. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Yes, but you still needed to apply the change that I mentioned, too. That's why fixing just that `<action>` didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix it.
Thanks for your help.
I think I know what fixed it (thanks Pawel) here's my explanation:

I removed the `exported = "true"` and `enabled = "true"` since i found out that they are irrelevant, at least for my project. This does not have anything to do with the problem.
I did change the `.MySMSReceiver` from `SMS_RECEIVED` to `SMS_DELIVER` which Pawel told me to. I did and at first it didn't work but now it works. Must have been my mistake sorry!
Thanks for the help! And sorry for messing up on your answer Pawel.

Here's my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imessages">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".editNameAndPhoto_activity" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".MySMSReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
                <action android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".MyMMSReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".QuickResponseService"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".Messages" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```